# Scrolling up with jQuery taps a button

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I tried to automatically scroll up with jQuery. It scrolls up like it should but it clicks a button at the bottom of the site. This problem occurs only if I open the webapp from the homescreen of an iPhone. If I load the site in the browser of the same iPhone, everything works fine.
Are there any differences between webapps loaded in the browser or webapps started from the iOS-homescreen?

Comment: Maybe you're having an element's name/id collision?